# Where Raw query on Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Hi i'm having hard time getting the right query for this scenario.

How can i get all users with 3 customers.

Costumers Table:

```
userid  | customerid
______________________

1       | 10
1       | 11
1       | 12
2       | 13
2       | 22
2       | 23
1       | 24
3       | 50
```

the expected result in the query should be users with the id 1 and 2.

I have tried 'whereRaw' in 'Laravel' but i just cant get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use groupBy() and havingRaw()

```
User::select(['user_id'])
->groupBy('user_id')
->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) >= 3')
->get();
```

this will return user id that have 3 or more customer id

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` with conditional filtering using `HAVING` clause:

To find total number of customers with a user, we can use `COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)` to count the unique number of customers.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM your_table
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) = 3
```

**Note:**

- If the table structure ensures that `(user_id, customer_id)` combination is `UNIQUE`; then you can use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)`
- If you are looking for users with **atleast** three customers, then you can use `>= 3` instead in the condition.